# How to return MultipleParams to Javascript using in ios?

Tags: ios, cordova

Hi i want to return image AS Base64sting and Float value's to Javascript using cordova
 ,How to achieve it?

using Json object i am getting

type error:Undefind is not an object and memory exception

After which application just crashes

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your string in the below code and use this code in native to call js function.

NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"fetchedNativeValues()];
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

Here fetchedNativeValues() is the js function which we are calling from native.

now goto javascript file where fetchedNativeValues(param1,param2) is declared 
and fetch the string value and convert that string again into image.

function fetchedNativeValues(param1,param2){
       //you can get these parameters from native like this

}

Comment: thanks @ Piyush , i am now sending objects as a NSdictonary object in Cordova